# Can I give a whole set of styles supreme importance over other style declarations?

Tags: css

Is it possible to give a whole set of styles supreme importance?

Ie, early on you might have the following default css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

and inside it has

```
    body {
       background: #000;
    }

    h1 {
       color: #fff;
    }
```

But then(!) you decide to make things exciting and have some more css inside the  tag that is the same but different:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
       background: #fff;
    }

    h1 {
       color: #000;
    }
</style>
```

For whatever reason, the styles inside style.css that are linked in take importance over the ones I'm putting in statically.

What I'd like to know is, is there a way of umbrella'ing a whole bunch of styles so they take the highest importance? The best I know is

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
       background: #fff !important;
    }

    h1 {
       color: #000 !important;
    }
</style>
```

Which starts to get a bit tedious if there are many styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically in CSS if you add a selector that is the same further down in the document, the one closest to the end (the highest line number) will be taken into effect.

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
       background: #000;
    }

    h1 {
       color: #fff;
    }

    body {
       background: #fff;
    }

    h1 {
       color: #000;
    }
</style>
```

The background would be white and the font color black.

Comment: Yes, thats how its usually worked for me also. But does this same rule apply if you have a 'linked' css file, and then followed by styles written straight into <head><style type="text/css">...</style></head> ? Is it possible that my page loads the <head></head> styles first before my large .css file and so therefore even though styles.css is first in the code, its being thought of as being on top of the static head styles?

Comment: If you have the linked file above the style tag in your head section, the tag's styles will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

add a single class to `body`, ie `body class="stylecatcher"` or whatever

then you can style (and override default styles) easily

```
<style type="text/css">
    body.stylecatcher {
       background: #fff;
    }

    .stylecatcher h1 {
       color: #000;
    }
</style>
```

I didn't find it to be a good practise to use the !important selector.

Comment: Thanks for that, but for the way the current problem is structured this is not practical.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called specificity. From the w3 [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) and adobe [link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/css_specificity.html)